# When I run keytoll for get keyrelease display this error

Tags: android, react-native, keytool

1-Run powersell in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin

> keytool.exe exist

2-run

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore release-key.keystore -alias key-alias
>   -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

but show this error:

```
keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ keytool -genkey -v -keystore d:\release-key.keystore -alias key-alias ...
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (keytool:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Suggestion [3,General]: The command keytool was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\keytool". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be two solutions,

1. Go to **Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin** dir and open cmd or powershell there and run your command
2. You need to set **Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin** path in your system environment's path variable

   **EDIT**

actually  keytool resides in jre folder not in jdk.

so check this,

1. Go to **Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin** dir and open cmd or powershell there and run your command

   2. You need to set **Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin** path in your system environment's path variable

and make sure when you use first solution use `.\keytool.exe` instead of `keytool`

Comment: I did exactly that, but I get this

Comment: my environment was C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
that i change them to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin
thank for your help